# Ошибка импорта selenium

Tags: python, selenium, python-import

Установил selenium + geckodriver. В студии ошибок нет, но на этапе интерпретации вылазит ошибка импорта. Переустанавливать пробовал.[image: Изображение с ошибкой импорта]

Comment: Может, Вы используете виртуальное окружение?

Comment: А если в REPL запустить python и заимпортировать selenium из этой же папочки?

Comment: в среде разработки selenium установился в виртуальное окружение.

Comment: Опишите побуквенно (покнопочно), как вы устанавливали selenium и geckodriver, в каких программах, и как пытаетесь выполнять скрипт. Предположение уже высказано, вероятно вы не разобрались с виртуальным окружением, оно могло быть созданно автоматически вашим интерпретатором, а устанавливать selenium вы могли в системный Python, а не в виртуальный